# Error after upgrading from React Native 0.45.1 to 0.46.4

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

```
error: bundling failed: "Unable to resolve module `ReactNative` from `C:\\AnchorDev\\Anchor\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module does not exist in the module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`."
```

This is the error that I received after upgrading React Native from 0.45.1 to 0.46.4. I ran npm i but I still get the error. How do I resolve it?

Comment: I am only wondering if there is a way to fix this because I currently cannot run my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting `node_modules` folder and install packages again with `npm install`